# How do I configure the Dags folder to be able to see the example dags?

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow, and lacking some of the knowledge regarding the configurations. I am currently installing airflow through Helm on EKS. When I authenticate to the web-server I do not find any of of the dags.

[image]

When I run the container locally I am able to see the example dags. This the Docker file that I use to for the airflow-container:

```
FROM python:3.6.3

# supervisord setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Airflow setup
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/app/airflow
RUN pip install apache-airflow
COPY /dags/hello_world.py $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/
RUN airflow initdb
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

[Here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/chart/values.yaml) is the default configurations for the Helm chart for airflow that I currently deploy.

Am I setting the path wrong to my dags? If so, how do I set it up correctly to show the example dags?

Update:
I have tried setting `load_examples` to True via helm, like:

```
resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
  name  = "airflow-helm"
  repository = data.helm_repository.airflow.metadata[0].name
  chart = "airflow"
  cleanup_on_fail = true
  create_namespace = true

  set {
    name  = "config.core.load_examples"
    value = "True"
  }
}
```

But still does not seem to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the following block:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bee2cb53179fcc70b64c30d9c49c72f0fa3e01da/chart/values.yaml#L646

```yaml
config:
  core:
    dags_folder: '{{ include "airflow_dags" . }}'
    load_examples: 'False'
    colored_console_log: 'False'
```

change load_examples from `False` to `True`

Comment: +1 as that makes total sense. However, I have tried updating the value (updated my question with the details) but still does not seem to resolve my issue.